# Getting FraudPreprocessResult Declined message on Paypal PayfloPro response

Tags: paypal, coldfusion, paypal-sandbox, payflowpro

I'm very new to payment integration. Recently I created a test account and am trying to configure Paypal integration. When I call the API, passing the xmlformat request via coldfusion `<cfhttp>`, I am getting the following response message:

**Paypal Response:**

```
 <XMLPayResponse xmlns="http://www.paypal.com/XMLPay">
        <ResponseData>
            <Vendor>UserName</Vendor>
            <Partner>paypal</Partner>
            <TransactionResults>
                <TransactionResult>
                    <Result>12</Result>
                    <FraudPreprocessResult> <Message>Review: More than one rule was triggered for Review</Message></FraudPreprocessResult>
                    <Message>Declined</Message>
                </TransactionResult>
            </TransactionResults>
        </ResponseData>
    </XMLPayResponse>
```

**My xml format is**

```
<cfxml variable="XMLDoc">
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<XMLPayRequest version="2.0">
  <RequestData>
    <cfif len("UserName")><Vendor>#XMLFormat("UserName")#</Vendor></cfif>
    <Partner>#XMLFormat("PayPal")#</Partner>
    <Transactions>
      <Transaction> <!--- Id="#TxId#" --->
        <Sale>
          <PayData>
            <Invoice>
              <CustIP>#XMLFormat("127.0.0.1")#</CustIP>
              <MerchantDescription>#XMLFormat("Test description")#</MerchantDescription>
              <!---<MerchantServiceNum>#XMLFormat(Attributes.Extra.ServiceNumber)#</MerchantServiceNum>--->
              <Date>#DateFormat(Now(),"YYYYMMDD")#</Date>
              <BillFrom/>
              <BillTo>
                <Name>#XmlFormat("Billing to Address")#</Name>
              </BillTo>
              <ShipFrom/>
              <ShipTo/>
              <ShippingAmt Currency="USD">#DecimalFormat(2.50)#</ShippingAmt>
              <TaxAmt Currency="USD">#DecimalFormat(1.12)#</TaxAmt>
              <ItemAmt Currency="USD">#DecimalFormat(10.20)#</ItemAmt>
              <TotalAmt Currency="USD">#DecimalFormat(13.82)#</TotalAmt>
              <CustomerHostName>#XmlFormat(CGI.SERVER_NAME)#</CustomerHostName>
              <CustomerBrowser>#XmlFormat(CGI.HTTP_USER_AGENT)#</CustomerBrowser>
            </Invoice>
            <Tender>
              <Card>
                <CardNum>#XmlFormat(4242424242424242)#</CardNum>
                <ExpDate>#DateFormat(CreateDate(2020, 12, 1), "YYYYMM")#</ExpDate>
                <CVNum>#XmlFormat(123)#</CVNum>
                <NameOnCard>#XmlFormat("VISA")#</NameOnCard>
              </Card>
            </Tender>
          </PayData>
        </Sale>
      </Transaction>
    </Transactions>
  </RequestData>
  <RequestAuth>
    <UserPass>
      <User>#XMLFormat("UserName")#</User>
      <Password>#XMLFormat("Password")#</Password>
    </UserPass>
  </RequestAuth>
</XMLPayRequest>
</cfxml>
```

**ColdFusion cfhttp request:**

```
<cfhttp url="https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com" method="post" timeout="60" throwonerror="yes">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="text/xml">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="X-VPS-CLIENT-TIMEOUT" value="60">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="X-VPS-VIT-OS-NAME" value="#Server.OS.Name#">
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#ToString(xml)#">
</cfhttp>
```

What did I do wrong here? Can anyone offer suggestions about the configuration, how to resolve this error or some ideas on how to integrate Paypal payment?

Comment: is this a sample or are you actually passing 127.0.0.1?

Comment: The error is telling you that your request is tripping a fraud trigger. Typically this is a mismatch of billing address information, bad CVV bad frequency (too many requests in a row for the same CC)... stuff like that. PP docs will tell you what the possibilities are and you will need to match them against what you are submitting

Comment: Thanks Mark A Kruger. Will check PP docs more.

Comment: yeah - there is usually a sample test you can run against the sandbox. Then change various things about it to aquaint yourself with the possible errors. Then, when these errors are thrown by actual user input (as they _will_ be :) you will know what you are up against.